# How to get the latest promoted build number for a dependency in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a grails app that depends on a custom grails plugin. In Jenkins, I want the release build for the app to depend on the latest promoted release build of the plugin. So, I thought I'd put a conditional in the BuildConfig.groovy to use an environment variable that has that value. So now I need a way to set an environment variable in Jenkins to the latest build number of that other job. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you can do the envisioned workflow manually (e.g. going into the main configuration and change a environment variable there), then you should be able to automate it using the [Jenkins Command Line Interface](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI). However, you can not directly change an environment variable in one job and read that changed value in another job.

Comment: That's not what I'm suggesting. I know the information is available at least to plugins since the Promoted Build Parameter has access to that information.

Comment: Just because an info is available to plugin, doesn't mean that you have access to it in the command line or in other words, it does not mean that this info is already exposed at the command line. However, if you can connect the release build of the app to the release promotion of the plugin (i.e. plugin promotion, triggers the release build of app) then the promotion can trigger the build. That means you can only have one release build per plugin promotion.